# Console application C# looping

Tags: c#, loops

Hi i am studing to be a programmer and this is a project i am working on. The console basically takes the users input (diameter) and tells you how many pizza slices you will get and the area of each slice. after telling them the slices and area of each, it must promt for new input. Slices are determined based on ranges such as 12 - 20" of diameter = 8 slices. a user has to enter in a range between 12" - 36" or they get an error message. Also if the user enters in a diameter of 36, it must show all of the other slices in decrements of 4, so 24 , 20, 16 ,12 , 8 . but if the diameter ends up falling under the 8 slices, it must only show that. hence 12 slices will show 8 slices and 12 slices.

lastly, we are learning about loops, we are to use the do while loop, and the for loop in this project.

this is what i have, and it doesnt work.

```
        //DECLARATIONS
        double circleArea;  // area of pizza
        double diameter; // diameter of the pizza
        double areaOfSlice; // area of the slices
        double radius; // half the diameter of the pizza
        double slices = 0; // number of pizza slices
        string message = ""; // a string to hold a message to the user
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_MASSIVE = 36;
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_EXTRA_LARGE = 30;
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_LARGE = 24;
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_MED = 16;
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_LOW = 12; // Low end on range scale for diameter
        const int SLICES_LOW_DIAMETER = 8; // number of pizza slices based on diameter
        const int SLICES_MID_DIAMETER = 12; // number of pizza slices based on diameter
        const int SLICES_HIGH_DIAMETER = 16; // number of pizza slices based on diameter
        const int SLICES_GIANT_DIAMETER = 24; // number of pizza slices based on diameter        
        bool needInput = true;
        const int END_PROGRAM = 0;




        // INPUT
        // Prompt for and get keyboard input

        Console.Write("Please enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program): ");  // get user to input diameter
        diameter = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); // read a line of text (string) from the keyboard,
        // convert that string to an double,
        // assign the resulting value to diameter

        // PROCESSING
        // determine if diameter meets requirements of 12" to 36"
        // if does not meet requirements show error message and have user enter in new diameter
        do
        {
            if (diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_LOW || diameter > DIAMETER_RANGE_MASSIVE)

            {
                message = "\nENTRY ERROR";
                message += "\nPizza must have a diameter in the range of 12” to 36” inclusive!";
                message += "\nPlease try again.";
            }



        else {    
            needInput = false;
                // determine the number of slices based on diameter


                if (diameter >= DIAMETER_RANGE_LOW && diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_MED)
                {
                    slices = (SLICES_LOW_DIAMETER);
                }
                else if (diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_LARGE)
                {
                    slices = (SLICES_MID_DIAMETER);
                }
                else if (diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_EXTRA_LARGE)
                {
                    slices = (SLICES_HIGH_DIAMETER);
                }
                else
                {
                    slices = (SLICES_GIANT_DIAMETER);
                }

                Console.Clear(); // clears console to show new output lines
                //OUTPUT
                for (int slicesAddFour = 8; slicesAddFour <=slices; slicesAddFour+=4) // for each slices
                {
                // determine the area of the slices
                radius = diameter / 2; // uses diameter to get radius
                circleArea = Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2); // uses math class to calculate circle area  
                areaOfSlice = Math.Round((circleArea / slices), 2); // divides circle area by slices, takes the result of above calculation and rounds

                Console.WriteLine("\nA {0}\" Pizza diameter: {0}\".", diameter); 
                message +=("\n==============================================");
                Console.WriteLine("\nCut in {0} slices results in an area of {1}\" per slice.",areaOfSlice,slices);

                }


        } //end of else

            message = ("\nPlease enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program)");
            needInput = true;
        } while (diameter != END_PROGRAM && needInput);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lab6B
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //DECLARATIONS
            double circleArea;  // area of pizza
            double diameter; // diameter of the pizza
            double areaOfSlice; // area of the slices
            double radius; // half the diameter of the pizza
            double slices = 0; // number of pizza slices
            const int INPUT_MAX = 36; // maximum entry for diameter
            const int DIAMETER_RANGE_EXTRA_LARGE = 30; // diameter range used to figure out slices
            const int DIAMETER_RANGE_LARGE = 24; // diameter range used to figure out slices
            const int DIAMETER_RANGE_MED = 16; // diameter range used to figure out slices
            const int INPUT_MIN = 12; // minimum entry for diameter
            const int SLICES_LOW_DIAMETER = 8; // number of pizza slices based on diameter
            const int SLICES_MID_DIAMETER = 12; // number of pizza slices based on diameter
            const int SLICES_HIGH_DIAMETER = 16; // number of pizza slices based on diameter
            const int SLICES_GIANT_DIAMETER = 24; // number of pizza slices based on diameter        
            bool needInput = true; // does the program need input true or false
            const int END_PROGRAM = 0; // 0 ends the program





            // INPUT
            // Prompt for and get keyboard input

            Console.Write("Please enter the diameter of your pizza: ");  // get user to input diameter
            diameter = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); // read a line of text (string) from the keyboard, 

            // convert that string to an double,
            // assign the resulting value to diameter

            while (diameter != END_PROGRAM && needInput) // Begin while loop

            {

                // PROCESSING

                // determine if diameter meets requirements of 12" to 36"
                // if does not meet requirements show error message and have user enter in new diameter


                if (diameter < INPUT_MIN || diameter > INPUT_MAX)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine( "\nENTRY ERROR\nPizza must have a diameter in the range of 12” to 36” inclusive!\nPlease try again.");
                }


                else
                {
                    needInput = false;
                    // determine the number of slices based on diameter


                    if (diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_MED)
                    {
                        slices = (SLICES_LOW_DIAMETER);
                    }
                    else if (diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_LARGE)
                    {
                        slices = (SLICES_MID_DIAMETER);
                    }
                    else if (diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_EXTRA_LARGE)
                    {
                        slices = (SLICES_HIGH_DIAMETER);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        slices = (SLICES_GIANT_DIAMETER);
                    }

                    Console.Clear(); // clears console to show new output lines

                    //OUTPUT

                    Console.WriteLine("\nA {0}\" Pizza diameter: {0}\".", diameter);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n==============================================");

                    for (int slicesAddFour = 8; slicesAddFour <= slices; slicesAddFour += 4) // for each slices
                    {
                        // determine the area of the slices
                        radius = diameter / 2; // uses diameter to get radius
                        circleArea = Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2); // uses math class to calculate circle area  
                        areaOfSlice = Math.Round((circleArea / slicesAddFour), 2); // divides circle area by slices, takes the result of above calculation and rounds


                        Console.WriteLine("\nCut in {0} slices results in an area of {1}\" per slice.", slicesAddFour, areaOfSlice);


                    }


                } //end of else

                Console.Write("\nPlease enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to exit): ");
                diameter = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Clear(); // clears console to show new output lines

                // set the need input value back to true for new entry
                needInput = true;

             } // end of while loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you read in the data once, and then continue looping without getting any new data.  If you move

```
Console.Write("Please enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program): ");  // get user to input diameter
diameter = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); // read a line of text (string) from the keyboard,
```

inside of the loop, it should fix your problem

Answer (score 4):

Move these two lines:

```
Console.Write("Please enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program): ");  // get user to input diameter
            diameter = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); // read a line of text (string) from the keyboard,
```

Inside of the do/while loop within it.

Your code becomes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SOHelp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              //DECLARATIONS
        double circleArea;  // area of pizza
        double diameter; // diameter of the pizza
        double areaOfSlice; // area of the slices
        double radius; // half the diameter of the pizza
        double slices = 0; // number of pizza slices
        string message = ""; // a string to hold a message to the user
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_MASSIVE = 36;
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_EXTRA_LARGE = 30;
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_LARGE = 24;
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_MED = 16;
        const int DIAMETER_RANGE_LOW = 12; // Low end on range scale for diameter
        const int SLICES_LOW_DIAMETER = 8; // number of pizza slices based on diameter
        const int SLICES_MID_DIAMETER = 12; // number of pizza slices based on diameter
        const int SLICES_HIGH_DIAMETER = 16; // number of pizza slices based on diameter
        const int SLICES_GIANT_DIAMETER = 24; // number of pizza slices based on diameter        
        bool needInput = true;
        const int END_PROGRAM = 0;




        // INPUT
        // Prompt for and get keyboard input


        // convert that string to an double,
        // assign the resulting value to diameter

        // PROCESSING
        // determine if diameter meets requirements of 12" to 36"
        // if does not meet requirements show error message and have user enter in new diameter
        string message = "Please enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program): ";

        do
        {
            Console.Write(message);  // get user to input diameter
            diameter = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); // read a line of text (string) from the keyboard,

            if (diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_LOW || diameter > DIAMETER_RANGE_MASSIVE)

            {
                message = "\nENTRY ERROR";
                message += "\nPizza must have a diameter in the range of 12” to 36” inclusive!";
                message += "\nPlease try again.";
            }



        else {    
            needInput = false;
                // determine the number of slices based on diameter


                if (diameter >= DIAMETER_RANGE_LOW && diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_MED)
                {
                    slices = (SLICES_LOW_DIAMETER);
                }
                else if (diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_LARGE)
                {
                    slices = (SLICES_MID_DIAMETER);
                }
                else if (diameter < DIAMETER_RANGE_EXTRA_LARGE)
                {
                    slices = (SLICES_HIGH_DIAMETER);
                }
                else
                {
                    slices = (SLICES_GIANT_DIAMETER);
                }

                Console.Clear(); // clears console to show new output lines
                //OUTPUT
                for (int slicesAddFour = 8; slicesAddFour <=slices; slicesAddFour+=4) // for each slices
                {
                // determine the area of the slices
                radius = diameter / 2; // uses diameter to get radius
                circleArea = Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2); // uses math class to calculate circle area  
                areaOfSlice = Math.Round((circleArea / slices), 2); // divides circle area by slices, takes the result of above calculation and rounds

                Console.WriteLine("\nA {0}\" Pizza diameter: {0}\".", diameter); 
                message +=("\n==============================================");
                Console.WriteLine("\nCut in {0} slices results in an area of {1}\" per slice.",areaOfSlice,slices);

                }


        } //end of else

            message = ("\nPlease enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program)");
            needInput = true;
        } while (diameter != END_PROGRAM && needInput);
    }
}
        }
```